# Render submit row without {{ form(form) }} - Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder, symfony2-easyadmin

I would like to modify the displaying of my forms.

So I used

```
{{ form_row(form.field1) }}
{{ form_row(form.field2) }}
{{ form_row(form.field3) }}
{{ form_row(form.field4) }}
```

Instead of

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

The problem is that without this, the submit row (provide with easy-admin bundle in new and edit view) is not displayed.
But if I put back `{{ form(form) }}` then the submit row is displayed.

I also tried `{{ form_rest(form) }}` with no success.

Answer (score 3):

EasyAdmin hardcoded the submit button for the edit and new views as you can see here : https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig#L428

So you can just put a regular button if you want to customize your form :

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-save"></i> {{ 'action.save'|trans(_trans_parameters, 'messages') }}
</button>
```

Comment: Hi ! Thank you very much for those information. Do you know if it's possible to add the entire action panel ? I've read the piece of code which add those actions but I don't know how to include all the normal actions for new and edit view (save, delete, back) ?

Comment: @Lucien these actions are wrapped with a `{% block item_actions %}` block. Can you try to override it?

Comment: I've created an issue in EasyAdmin to discuss about not hardcoding these actions in the template and making them easier to override: https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle/issues/1181

Comment: @JavierEguiluz Thank you for helping me ! 
How can I just display all the actions buttons ? Call {{ block item_actions }}results in a "Unexpected token "name" of value "item_actions". I've modified my form, and I just want to display save, delete and back actions without override them.

Comment: @JavierEguiluz I tried to troubleshoot during the week end but I still not find how to display the row containing the actions :/